# EF Core Long time to download files (varbinary) from the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

Stores part of the files in the database in a table containing IdFile (PK) and FileBytes (varbinary(max)) columns. For the test, I uploaded 3 files with a size of about 15MB, when I try to download it using EF Core, it takes a very long time, about 45s, downloading the IdFile itself is no problem. The same query that EF generates running in SQL Management studio takes 2s. Is there anything that can be done to make EF download such files faster? Changing the file storage location, unfortunately, cannot be changed.

SQL from EF CORE

```
SELECT [f].[ID_FILE], [f].[FILE_BYTES]
FROM [FILE] AS [f]
WHERE [f].[ID_FILE] IN (CAST(1 AS bigint), CAST(2 AS bigint), CAST(3 AS bigint))
```

Comment: This is a known problem which has existed for a long time. There are some paths when reading these blobs async that are just terribly slow. See https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/593.  In EF6 it worked better if you didn't use async calls, not sure if this still holds true for EFCore though.

Comment: Use `AsNoTracking`, If you don't need to track changes to the entities retrieved from the database

Comment: It's probably quicker in SSMS because the default value for Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid > Maximum Characters Retrieved (Non-XML data) is only 65535. In other words SSMS would only be downloading 192 KiB of your 15 MiB of file data.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

I changed the way of fetching data from asynchronous to synchronous

From

```
await dataContext.File.Where(w => idFiles.Contains(w.IdFile)).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

To

```
dataContext.File.Where(w => idFiles.Contains(w.IdFile)).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

And now exactly the same entries download 2s instead of 45s